# I am completing a journal paper that uses apalike referencing style in latex. I used natbib in my tex file

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, natbib, apa-style, doi

I used natbib in my tex file. The problem is that the output file does not include the doi, isbn, and issn information. How do I include DOI and ISSN in Apalike reference style in Latex

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)! Could you edit your code to begin with your `\documentclass{}` and end with `\end{document}` , a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please. It makes copy and pasting easier when the code can be compiled and also we do not need to guess what commands or packages you are using.

Comment: `apalike` is very old and does not support doi and issn fields. You might want to switch to [biblatex-apa](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa)

Comment: If you want to stay with BibTeX, I suggest you (a) change `\bibliographystyle{apalike}` to `\bibliographystyle{apacite}` and (b) change `\usepackage{natbib}` to `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`.

Comment: \documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{hidelinks,colorlinks,breaklinks=true,urlcolor=black,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,bookmarksopen=false,pdftitle={Title},pdfauthor={Author}}
\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction} \citep{zebin2012modeling},\citep{tokhi2008flexible},\citep{lochan2016review,kiang2015review,tokhi2008flexible}.
\phantomsection
\bibliographystyle{apalike} 
\bibliography{TLFM_22022023}
\end{document}

Comment: Thanks, but it does not include the ISSN and ISBN.